# MongoDB/doctrine: can't nest $or in $and

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm having trouble nesting multiple two-operand `$or` operations within an `$and` operation. The conclusion of [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/doctrine-user/fVkPvHZwQAE/discussion) sounds similar what I need, but I'm unable to get it to work. Here's JavaScript of what I'm trying to do:

```
db.Business.find(
  {
    $and:
      [
        { $or: [{nm: /American/}, {dsc: /American/}] },
        { $or: [{nm: /Mega/}, {dsc: /Mega/}] }
      ]
  }
)
```

That works in the MongoDB interactive shell.

And here's some PHP that looks ok to me but doesn't work (causes infinite recursion where indicated):

```php
$q = $doctrineOdm->createQueryBuilder('Business');
foreach (array('American','Mega') as $keyword) {
  $r = new \MongoRegex('/'.$keyword.'/i');
  $q->addAnd(
    $q->addOr($q->expr()->field('nm')->equals($r))
      ->addOr($q->expr()->field('dsc')->equals($r))
  );
}
print_r($q->getQuery()->getQuery()); // infinite recursion
$cursor = $q->getQuery()->execute();
```

Any ideas?

[Crossposted here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/doctrine-user/y5VqSEfB9Es/discussion).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you need to build a separate subquery before adding it to `$q`.

`$q->addAnd(...)` is evaluated immediately and adds itself to `$q`, but you want it to wait.

I don't have this package installed so I can't test, but this is just a hunch. Hope it helps.

```
$q = $doctrineOdm->createQueryBuilder('Business');
foreach (array('American','Mega') as $keyword) {
  $r = new \MongoRegex('/'.$keyword.'/i');
  $q->addAnd(
    $q->expr()->addOr($q->expr()->field('nm')->equals($r))
              ->addOr($q->expr()->field('dsc')->equals($r))
  );
}
print_r($q->getQuery()->getQuery()); // infinite recursion
$cursor = $q->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: That was it exactly! Thank you! Adding `->expr()` indeed delays adding the `$or` expression until the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follows:

```
$filters = array(
     new \MongoRegex('/American/i'),
     new \MongoRegex('/Mega/i')
);
$q = $doctrineOdm->createQueryBuilder('Business')
                 -> field('nm')  ->in($filters)
                 -> field('dsc') ->in($filters);

print_r($q->getQuery()->getQuery()); // infinite recursion
$cursor = $q->getQuery()->execute();
```